# Is it possible to pass a range of values to the glob function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, file, search, glob

I have a big number of files within a directory and I want to search for specific files with PHP `glob` function. This is my code:

```
/* SAMPLE FILE NAME: PR330037JED10220161204.csv */
$dir        = 'Files/Payment/';
$prefix     = 'PR';
$vendorNo   = '330037';
$region     = 'JED';
$date       = '20161204';
$files      = glob($dir.$prefix.$vendorNo.$region."*".$date.".csv");
```

It works fine, but I would like to check if the date part matches a range of dates. How do I change the glob expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop through the date range. try following code

```
$dir        = 'Files/Payment/';
$prefix     = 'PR';
$vendorNo   = '330037';
$region     = 'JED';

$begin = new DateTime( '2016-12-05' );
$end = new DateTime( '2016-12-10' );

for($i = $begin; $begin <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')) {
    $date = $i->format("Ymd");
    $files = glob($dir.$prefix.$vendorNo.$region."*".$date.".csv");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `GLOB_BRACE` FLAG that [glob()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) supports.

Example :

```
<?php

$dir        = 'Files/Payment/';
$prefix     = 'PR';
$vendorNo   = '330037';
$region     = 'JED';
$date       = '20161204';

$d1 = new DateTime();
$d2 = new DateTime('-1 day');
$d3 = new DateTime('-1 week');
// Add your dates here. or even better find a way to generate the below list in an automated way, according to your needs
$daysList = $d1->format('Ymd').','.$d2->format('Ymd').','.$d3->format('Ymd');

$pattern      = $dir.$prefix.$vendorNo.$region."*"."{".$daysList."}".".csv";

$files      = glob($pattern, GLOB_BRACE);
```

Answer (score 1):

`glob()` doesn't support ranges. The best you can do with `glob` is to list the dates using `GLOB_BRACE` option:

```
$date = '{20161204,20161205,20161206}';
$pattern  = sprintf('%s/%s%s%s*%s.csv',
  $dir, $prefix, $vendorNo, $region, $date);

$files = glob($pattern, GLOB_BRACE);
```

A more flexible way is to iterate the directory, parse the date from the filename, and check if it belongs to an interval of dates:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));

$date_from = 20161204;
$date_to   = 20161206;

$pattern  = '/^' . preg_quote($prefix . $vendorNo . $region, '/') .
  '.*(?P<date>\d{8})\.csv$/';

$it->rewind();
while ($it->valid()) {
  if (!$it->isDot()) {
    $path = $it->key();
    $basename = basename($path);
    if (preg_match($pattern, $basename, $matches) &&
      isset($matches['date']) &&
      $matches['date'] >= $date_from &&
      $matches['date'] <= $date_to)
    {
      echo $basename, PHP_EOL;
    }
  }

  $it->next();
}
```